# Generate 2d array with Javascript/es6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is there a more functional way to create a 2d array in Javascript than what I have here? Perhaps using `.apply`?

```
generatePuzzle(size) {
  let puzzle = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    puzzle[i] = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < size; j++) {
      puzzle[i][j] = Math.floor((Math.random() * 200) + 1);
    }
  }
  return puzzle;
}
```

For instance, in python, you can do something like `[[0]*4]*4` to create a 4x4 list

Comment: You can use forEach, map, etc. to create a 2D array and map to random numbers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const repeat = (fn, n) => Array(n).fill(0).map(fn);
const rand = () => Math.floor((Math.random() * 200) + 1);
const puzzle = n => repeat(() => repeat(rand, n), n);
```

And then `puzzle(3)`, eg, will return a 3x3 matrix filled with random numbers.

Comment: can you please explain each line separately ?

Answer (score -1):

With lodash just like below:

```
const _ = require('lodash');

function generatePuzzle(size) {
  return _.times(size, () => _.times(size, () => (Math.random() * 200) + 1));
}
```

Comment: Sure, but the OP isn't using Lodash and what's the point of adding a whole library just for one tiny operation?

Comment: Well I have lodash on most codebases

Comment: In any case it's very easy to implement own version of "times"